# Build failure with docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have changed a running docker-compose application to include folders for future Dockerimage(s).

The code base is structured based on another docker-compose app with multiple Dockerfiles that works.

I just can't seem to find what causes the error here.

The file structure looks like:

```
ubuntu
│   docker-compose.yml    
└───Go
    │   Dockerfile
    │   data.go
    │   handlers.go
    │   main.go
    └───.well-known
    |    └───pki-validation
    |          val.txt  
    └───ssl
    |    key
    |    cert
    └───static
    |   └───css
    |   └───imgs
    |   └───js
    |   └───favicon.ico
    └───views
        *.html
```

The docker-compose.yml

```
version : '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: mycontainer.com
    build:
      context: ./Go
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: always
```

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./.well-known /.well-known
COPY ./ssl /ssl
COPY ./views /views
COPY ./data.go .
COPY ./handlers.go .
COPY ./main.go .
RUN cd static
COPY ./static /static
RUN go mod init mymodule
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build $(ls -1 *.go)
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["go", "run", "."]
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` I get the following error.

```
found packages Go (data.go) and main (main.go) in /app
The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build $(ls -1 *.go)' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build
```

Comment: It looks like you have put files ('data.go' and 'main.go') that are in different packages into the same folder. Either change the package declaration in 'data.go' or move it to a separate folder.

Comment: Nice catch! My IDE renamed them behind my back...

Comment: In your dockerfile, you copy everything into `/app` and then copy a bunch of the files again int duplicate directories. This isn't the main build issue, but it would be better to `COPY` once and then use the `mv` command within a `RUN` statement to move the files where you want them.

edit: I'd also recommend putting your go code into directories that form a valid package structure and create your `go mod` file as a real module in your source and not generate it inside your Dockerfile. Lastly, use something like `go build -o main main.go`. You shouldn't need to specify all `*.go files`

Answer (score 0):

The `/Go` folder contains files ('data.go' and 'main.go') that are in different [packages](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages). The solution depends upon the projects structure; either change the package declaration in 'data.go' or move it to a separate folder.

As per the comments in this case the package declaration had been changed inadvertently.